# How can I add header in my retrofit using OAuth2?

Tags: android

I am developing an app. I am using retrofit2 for API call. I have to add a header using OAuth2. But I don't know how to do?
Here is the
KEY 
"uuid"
"profile_pic"

and I have asked to add OAuth2 for header. Have to use some token. But I am not clear whether I have to pass token in header or use another way for OAuth2

```
public interface ApiInterface {

@Headers("Accept: application/json")
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("user/profile-pic")
Call<Model> updateProfilePic(@Field("uuid") String uuid,
                             @Field("profile_pic") String profilePic,
                             @Header("OAuth2") String OAuth2);
```

}

```
class APIClient {

static Retrofit getClient() {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();


    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();



    return retrofit;
}
```

}

```
private void updateUserPic() {

    SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("UserData" ,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String uuid  = sp.getString("User_Uuid",null);
    String token = sp.getString("User_Token", null);

    Log.v("uuid", uuid);

    Call<Model> call =
            apiInterface.updateProfilePic(uuid, profilePic, token);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, Response<Model> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                Log.v("Response", response.message());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Model> call, Throwable t) {
            call.cancel();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: We can't really help you if you don't tell us what you've tried

Comment: I have added the code @Ahmad